# How to open emulator in intellij?

Tags: intellij-idea, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I'm trying to launch emulator from intellij Terminal but it's keep giving error " PANIC ".

I also tried code mentioned below in my base class before test.

```
 void laughEmulator() throws IOException {

        try {
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("emulator @Demo");
            System.out.println("start emulator");
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (Exception ex) {ex.printStackTrace();}
```

Help me to launch emulator from terminal and with my code too.
i'm using intellij since week so not familiar with IDE.

Comment: Does it work from OS terminal?

Comment: Command from emulator folder YES. but if i give command `emulator @Demo` direct it will give same error PANIC.

Comment: Probably you should set working folder before executing command? If it works from OS terminal it should also work in IDE terminal.

Comment: actually i don't know how to do that.

Comment: You could open terminal in IDE, navigate to emulator folder and run command there. Will it work?

Comment: i know tat way but what should i do to run with command? that's the question.

Comment: You could set "Working directory" field to emulator folder in you run configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- actually new android sdk has `emulator.exe` in two folder in emulator folder and in tools folder.
- so first give path of emulator as mentioned below.

  ```
  C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator
  C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\bin
  ```
- and than delete emulator.exe from tools folder.
- then restart cmd and hit command emulator @emulator_name